# trying to send extended characters via ajax

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery Ajax function which sends the following data to a asp page.

name=Högberg

This is the ajax function...

```
function senddata(){
jQuery.ajax({
url: "/vsmtp.asp",
type: 'POST',
data: 'name=Högberg',
cache: false,
success: function(data){
    alert('success');
              } 
       })
}
```

My problem is that when I look at the actual text in the POST in Firebug it is sending the following.

```
name=Hï¿½gberg
```

How can I encode it such that is sends the correct characters? Thanks.

Comment: What character set is your page in?

Comment: I have tried all available settings in FF. (UTF-8, ISO8859-1,etc...) all the same, does not work

Comment: @user What about the character sets on the actual files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I needed to simply escape the data to get it working.

```
function senddata(){
var str= "name=Högberg";
jQuery.ajax({
url: "/vsmtp.asp",
type: 'POST',
data: escape(str),
cache: false,
success: function(data){
alert('success');
              } 
       })
}
```

Comment: I was having a similar problem, but only in Firefox and Safari. IE8, Opera and Chrome posted the extended characters okay. However, using escape and unescape fixed it.